# The Metric Tensor, A Body of Mass m and Minkowski Space

Tags: differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, tensors, general-relativity

> By saying the body has mass m, we mean that the metric approaches that of Minkowski space for large r and that
>
> $$g_{00} \sim 1-2m/r$$

This was under a section in General Relativity by Woodhouse titled The Fiedl of a Static Spherical Body

I have no idea how the sentence implies the equation (so obviously)? I cannot see why we are only considering the 00 component and the right hand side I have no idea.

Comment: I cannot work out how to do ~, \widetilde didnt work either

Comment: Try "\$\sim\$" and see what you get.  Does in look like $\sim$?

Comment: @RobertLewis done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a *Non-rotating* and *Electrically neutral* massive body on a spherical-symmetric *static* spacetime, the appropriate metric is the *Schwarzschild metric*:

$$ds^2 = -(1-2m/r)dt^2+(1-2m/r)^{-1} dr^2 +r^2d\theta^2+r^2\sin^2 \theta d\phi^2$$
the $00$ component of the above metric (in the form of line-element) is the factor multiplying $dt^2$, for large "$r$" i.e. $r>>2m$, this factor is $\sim 1$, then this metric is reduced to the *Minkowski metric*:

$$ds^2 = c^2dt^2-dx^2-dy^2-dz^2$$

Just set $c=1$.

However, this is an exact solution, in ~1915 (Before Schwarzschild found that solution) Einstein derived an approximate solution (first order approximation) for calculating Mercury's orbit around sun assuming that mercury has a mass negligible to the sun's mass  and moves around the sun according to [geodesic equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_in_general_relativity) and then used perturbational methods. The solution that einstein found is a correction to newtonian-gravity, this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newtonian_limit) explain the concept of newtonian-limit in the context of General relativity.

you can find a full derivation in this [pdf](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1411/1411.7370.pdf).

Comment: Hi @Zober Thanks for posting your answer. I have changed the math writing to latex which we use on this site. Please could you check that I copied it over correctly. Thanks

Comment: Hello @Permian. It's correct, with exception of the (1-2m/r)-1dr², which the correct form is [(1-2m/r)^-1]dr².

Comment: Oh, and the (1-2m/r)dt² has a minus sign on the front.

Comment: How can the $00$ component only be the factor mulitplying $dt^2$? Where would you get all the components $ab$ where $a\neq b$?

Comment: The easiest answner is that the metric tensor has to be a covariant symmetric tensor, i.e. when you invert a component AB to BA, nothing changes, and in the definition of Schwarzschild metric, all components AB with A≠B are 0.  if interests you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deriving_the_Schwarzschild_solution a Wikipedia's article showing the derivation of that metric using einstein's general relativity.

Comment: thanks @zober..

Comment: Actually, in my book the schwartzchild metric is derived afterwards. So it must be possible to answer this without using the schwartzchild metric a priori

Comment: Ye, you're correct. it's possible to find an approximate form of that metric. I made some edits on the post, i hope it helps.

Comment: thanks. I find it slightly odd that you know so much geometry and relativity and dont know latex. If you are interested, I have a number of other questions on GR that are still open